# Trying to iterate through a list but I keep recieving an error

Tags: python, finance, mibian

I am trying to get the option call price for different stock prices. I keep receiving an error stating that float() argument must be a string or a number. Here is the code:

```
import mibian

price = [100,101,102,103,104]




c = 0.0
for i in price:
    #BS([underlyingPrice, strikePrice, interestRate, daysToExpiration], volatility=x, callPrice=y, putPrice=z)
    c[i] = mibian.BS([price, 100, 0,5], volatility=20)
print c.callPrice
```

Here is the error code:

```
self.underlyingPrice = float(args[0])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: Try printing out `args[0]` right before you try converting it to a float. The error message is telling you that `args[0]` isn't something that can be converted to a float. It may be a list or something instead (though we can't really tell from your question as it is).

Comment: `args` is not defined. Please post `args`

Comment: I assume args is price = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104]

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `c` to be a float:

```
c = 0.0
```

Then in the for loop you're accessing it as a dict:

```
c[i] = mibian.BS([price, 100, 0, 5], volatility=20)
```

Then after the for loop you are accessing it like an object:

```
print c.callPrice
```

There is no way this code will work. Please update your question to include what it is you want to accomplish.

**EDIT**: From reading your comments on my answer, this is what I think you want. Note: `c` is a dictionary of objects returned by `mibian.BS`.

```
import mibian

price = [100,101,102,103,104]
c = {}
for i in price:
    c[i] = mibian.BS([price, 100, 0,5], volatility=20)
    print c[i].callPrice
```

Comment: This is how it is called...c = mibian.BS([100,100,0,5], volatility=20)
print c.callPrice... this is what it returns: 0.933831922852... I want to do this for each price in the list.

Comment: So does is `c` equal to `0.933831922852` or is `c.callPrice` equal to `0.933831922852`?

Comment: It equals c.callPrice.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`c[i] = mibian.BS([price[i], 100, 0,5], volatility=20)`